# DIV overlay with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm about to redesign my website, and i want to make it more interesting vit some parralax effect. So here's my idea: I want 3 boxes, which overlay each other (and make the 2. and 3. box blurry, but it doesn't matter now). I would put it to the top of the site. So here's the parallax thing: I want it to move with the scrolling, something like this:
[PICTURE](http://goo.gl/EgkDwW)

I tried to search for it, or code it by myself, but i failed :(

Has anybody got some cool stuff to do this?

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/ - This is a good tutorial. Draws attention on sprites in this tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definetely this is your page:

```
http://stephband.info/jparallax/
```

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <title>jQuery.parallax</title>

    <script>document.documentElement.className = 'js';</script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Force latest IE rendering engine & Chrome Frame -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <!-- Make IE recognise HTML5 elements for styling -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <strong>Warning!</strong>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 so some elements on this page are simulated using JScript. Unfortunately your browser has JScript disabled. Please enable it in order to display this page.
    </noscript>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Disable image toolbar in IE6 -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" /><![endif]-->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stephband.info/css/template.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stephband.info/css/template.theme.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stephband.info/css/site.layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stephband.info/css/docs.classes.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stephband.info/css/demos.theme.css" />

    <!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.info/css/template.layout.32em.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.info/css/template.layout.48em.css" media="all" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.infocss/template.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.infocss/template.ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.infocss/template.ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stephband.infocss/template.ie6.css" /><![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.parallax.css" />

    <style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        #wrapper {
            width: 60em;
        }

        .button {
            background: #2f3134;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 60px; height: 60px;
            margin: 3.2em 3.2em 0 0;
        }

        #viewport {
            float: left; position: relative; background: #2f3134;
            width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 6.4em 3.2em 0 2.4em;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }

        #mouseport {
            float: left; position: relative; background: #2f3134;
            width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 6.4em 3.2em 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }

        .layer_1 { position: absolute; width: 45px; height: 45px; z-index: 101; }
        .layer_2 { position: absolute; width: 48px; height: 48px; z-index: 102; }
        .layer_3 { position: absolute; width: 52px; height: 52px; z-index: 103; }
        .layer_4 { position: absolute; width: 58px; height: 58px; z-index: 104; }
        .layer_5 { position: absolute; width: 67px; height: 67px; z-index: 105; }
        .layer_6 { position: absolute; width: 80px; height: 80px; z-index: 106; }

        .tl, .tr, .bl, .br {
            width: 11px; height: 11px;
        }

        .tl { background: url('http://stephband.info/images/corner_dark_tl.png'); }
        .tr { background: url('http://stephband.info/images/corner_dark_tr.png'); }
        .bl { background: url('http://stephband.info/images/corner_dark_bl.png'); }
        .br { background: url('http://stephband.info/images/corner_dark_br.png'); }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="site_header" id="page_header">
        <div class="site_wrap wrap">
            <a class="logo_thumb thumb" href="http://stephband.info" title="stephband" rel="index">
                <h1>stephband.info</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="site_wrap wrap">
        <h2>jParallax Demos <a href="thumbnails.html">next</a></h2>

        <div id="wrapper" class="clear">
            <div id="viewport">
                <!-- Parallax layers -->
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/1.png" alt="" class="layer_1"/>
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/2.png" alt="" class="layer_2"/>
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/3.png" alt="" class="layer_3"/>
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/4.png" alt="" class="layer_4"/>
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/5.png" alt="" class="layer_5"/>
                <img src="http://webdev.stephband.info/jparallax/images/parallax_button/6.png" alt="" class="layer_6"/>
            </div>

            <div id="mouseport"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // Set up parallax layers
      jQuery("#viewport>img").parallax(
          { mouseport: jQuery("#mouseport") },            // Options
          { xparallax: '6px',    yparallax: '6px' },      // Layer 1
          { xparallax: '12px',   yparallax: '12px' },     // Layer 2
          { xparallax: '30px',   yparallax: '30px' },     // Layer 3
          { xparallax: '54px',   yparallax: '54px' },     // Layer 4
          { xparallax: '84px',   yparallax: '84px' },     // Layer 5
          { xparallax: '120px',  yparallax: '120px' }     // Layer 6
      );
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this encourages your creativity!